# Can additional indentation of the member name be avoided in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a C++ code base which often splits up member declaration into two lines (type and name). After setting up automatic code formatting within VS2017 the indentation of the code looks like the following:

```
class A
{
public:
   // comment Ctor
   A();

   // comment Dtor
   ~A();

   // comment A
   void
      foo();

   // comment B
   int
      bar;
};
```

We couldn't find a setting to prevent VS-2017 from additionally indenting `foo()` and `bar`. What we want to have is something like:

```
class A
{
public:
   // comment Ctor
   A();

   // comment Dtor
   ~A();

   // comment A
   void
   foo();

   // comment B
   int
   bar;
};
```

So I am just wondering if we missed something or if this is totally unusual or just not possible yet. Btw. the code is indented as expected for the function definition (no indentation there):

```
void
A::foo()
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Why the hell won't you keep return value and function name on the same line???

Comment: Have you tweaked the options in Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Indentation?

Comment: @Aconcagua it's apparently a GNU coding standard https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Formatting (not saying I approve of it though)

Comment: @Default At least they are pushing towards `char* a` instead of `char *a` this way... Very uncommon, still, would rather stay with some much more frequently used style such as Allman (my personal favourite; Horstmann somehow is interesting, too, wouldn't adopt it, though, solely for being too exotic...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option. The formatter does not support your style.

You could perhaps use clang-format for your formatting instead. The setting `IndentWrappedFunctionNames` controls this thing for function declarations and definitions. There does not appear to be such an option for variable declarations in clang-format either.